# Adding multiple products (csv files taking too much time)

Tags: api, import, csv, time

So we have  a CRM/Accounting/Sales/Inventory system called BrightPearl. This is used as our product database and we can import and export data into it using CSV. Files. I say product database and use the term loosely, one of my objectives here is to get on top of that. If we can manage the database of products better we can save a lot of manual entry of new products etc during the year. I also want to use the product database as a auto pricing tool. We use price breaks already but I’d like the spreadsheet to work these out so we have a set price list (which we currently don’t).

Then we have a spreadsheet we use to upload products to our magento site. 70% of the products in the product database will be eligible for the website but this is where it gets tricky. Because we provide “customisation” of clothing etc, we have had to customise a lot of the website in order to offer that facility (take a look here: ) so in the spreadsheet for the site we have to add additional columns for this which we wouldn’t use in the sheet for the product database. We get csv. Files from our suppliers with product info already so most of the leg work is done but in our industry we are talking about 10s of thousands of sku’s (f you consider a certain style of polo, size large, red is one sku…you see why there is so many!!) which need to be updated at least yearly when our wholesalers add/remove products from their offering or change pricing.

So all in all, I want to find a way to combine the 2 so it is sustainable for the future and takes away a lot of the manual typing into spreadsheets that we’re doing now.

I’ve been told that you can get different spreadsheets to “talk to eachother” so I am hoping there is some way we can do this.

Currently the process of adding products to Magento is a tedious process of having to add each product individually by entering their data into a csv file, this takes time having to add these products in individually to the csv files. Surely there should be a solution where the suppliers csv file can distribute to the other csv files. I have heard FileZilla can be used as a way of performing this.

TL;DR - Adding multiple products to website is taking too long by adding data to spreadsheets. Is there an easier solution to this?